# Las imagenes en el Slide no ocupan todo el ancho del contenedor, incluso utilizando object: cover. Ya probe. No sé que modificar para solucionarlo

Tags: css, slide

Intento hacer un slide.

El problema es que las imágenes ocupan espacio de otras.

Intenté resolviéndolo con `margin` `left` y `right` en las imágenes.

Luego me percaté que donde tenia que revisar era en el `.slider` varíe bastante las medidas de `width`. Tengo que repasar esos conceptos y como interactúan con el contenedor y demás.

//HTML

```
<div class="container-slider">
        <div class="slider" id="slider">
            <div class="slider__section">
                <img src="imagenes/5.jpg" alt="" class="slider__img img5">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__section">
                <img src="imagenes/7.png" alt="" class="slider__img">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__section">
                <img src="imagenes/8.png" alt="" class="slider__img">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__section">
                <img src="imagenes/9.png" alt="" class="slider__img img9">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__btn slider__btn--right" id="btn-right">&#62;</div>
        <div class="slider__btn slider__btn--left" id="btn-left">&#60;</div>
    </div>
    <script src="slider.js"></script>
```

//CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #F8F8F8;
}

.container-slider{
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 600%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #fff,
                0 15px 50px;
                position: relative;
                
}
.slider {
    display: flex;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    
    
}
.slider__section {
 
}
.slider__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    
}
.slider__btn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: monospace;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider__btn:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
.slider__btn--right { 
    right: 10px;
}
.slider__btn--left {
    left: 10px;
}




//JS


const slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
let sliderSection = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section");
let sliderSectionLast = sliderSection[sliderSection.length-1];

const btnLeft = document.querySelector("#btn-left");
const btnRight = document.querySelector("#btn-right");

slider.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',sliderSectionLast);

function Next() {
    let sliderSectionFirst = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section")[0];
    slider.style.marginLeft = "-200%"; // enfoco al 3ro
    slider.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
    setTimeout(function(){
        slider.style.transition = "none";
        slider.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',sliderSectionFirst);
        slider.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
    }, 500);
}



//


function Prev() {
    let sliderSection = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__section");
    let sliderSectionLast = sliderSection[sliderSection.length-1];
    slider.style.marginLeft = "0";
    slider.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
    setTimeout(function(){
        slider.style.transition = "none";
        slider.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin',sliderSectionLast);
        slider.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
    }, 500);
}

btnRight.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Next();
})

btnLeft.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Prev();
})

//setInterval(function() {
 //   Next();
//},5000);
```

Comment: Si la solución propuesta en la respuesta resolvió tu problema, por favor considera aceptarla para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes y de paso ganan reputación tú y Marcel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo debes quitar el height 100% de la siguiente línea CSS y lo tienes:

```
.slider__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

De igual forma te recomiendo utilizar alguna librería para los slider así te evitas este trabajo.

Comment: El problema con tu resolución es al dar al boton next. Las imagenes se enciman en el espacio de muestra y quedan dos imagenes en una

Comment: Yo las veo bien desde 2 navegadores distintos. Intenta refrescar caché o revisarlo desde una ventana de incógnito. También revisa las imágenes. Yo lo estoy probando con las imágenes del mismo tamaño todas.

Comment: Sigo con el problema incluso en Mozilla

Comment: Te paso el ejemplo donde lo veo bien, revisa porque seguro hay algún campo que no está del todo correcto o mismo las imágenes: https://codepen.io/marcelcl/pen/qBPWaPv

Comment: ¿Que pueden tener las imagenes que esten mal? ¿El tamaño?

Comment: Eran las imagenes el problema. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perfecto! Como comenta DjCrazy más arriba, si la solución propuesta en la respuesta resolvió tu problema, por favor considera aceptarla para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes. Debes hacer click en el "Check" en la columna izquierda de la respuesta. Saludos.